# Parent directory of a script

Tags: bash

So I am a rookie in Linux and I need some help. I have to write a bash script in which I have to use the parent directory of the script to create a file there, wherever the script would be. It should look like this:

If my script it's in "/home/student/", I need to create, using an in-script command another file called txt in /home/.   Any ideas please? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There's a subtlety if you want to be able to run your script from anywhere.

eg: if your script is in `/home/myHome/someDir/someOther`, and you want to create a file in `/home/myHome/someDir` wherever you are when you run your script.

To solve it, you just need to first derive the directory where your script is.

It can be done using:

```
 SCRIPT_DIRECTORY="$(dirname "$0")"
 touch "$SCRIPT_DIRECTORY/../myFile.txt"
```

---

Edit: Actually it can be even more subtle, if you want to handle symlinks. ie: if the symlink `/home/myHome/mySymlink` points at your script, and is the one actually being called, then the previous script will consider `/home/myHome/` instead of `/home/myHome/someDir/someOther`

To handle this case you can do

```
if [ -L "$0" ] && [ -x $(which readlink) ]; then
  ACTUAL_SCRIPT_FILE="$(readlink -mn "$0")"
else
  ACTUAL_SCRIPT_FILE="$0"
fi
SCRIPT_DIRECTORY="$(dirname "$ACTUAL_SCRIPT_FILE")"
touch "$SCRIPT_DIRECTORY/../myFile.txt"
```

Comment: The `cd` thing is a bit too much and has side-effects (btw, you need to `cd -` back at the end or use `pushd`/`popd`). Why not just `SCRIPT_DIR="$(dirname $0)"` and use the relative paths ?

Comment: It seems you're right: `SCRIPT_DIR="$(dirname $0)"` works. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Please use the quoted version in the answer itself: `"$(dirname $0)"` and `"$SCRIPT_DIRECTORY/../myFile.txt"`.

Comment: you're right: without the quotes it just fails if the path of the script contains a white space. Moreover, I believe we also need quotes around `$0` (ie: `"$(dirname "$0")"`) otherwise `dirname` fails. I just tested it, and this seems to work in every case. (Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Yeah, it seems quite bullet-proof now; except for null-byte injection, perhaps. :)

Answer (score 1):

use `..` to point to parent directory. So you could create a file using something like

```
MY_SCRIPTDIR="$(dirname $0)"
touch ${MY_SCRIPTDIR}/../abc.txt
```

From your command prompt or within shell script.

Comment: `..` is relative to the current directory, NOT to the directory where the script is. You need to grab the script location from `$0`.

Comment: Yeah Assuming OP knew where the script was running. But will modify the answer to be more specific. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the other answers either give you the current working directory instead of the directory the script is in, or they will not work if either the script or one of the directories along the way is a symbolic link rather than a real directory.

What will work is:

```
dirname $(readlink -f "$0")
```

Explanation:

- "$0" is the name of the script as you type it in your command line. Quoting is important for the case it contains whitespace.
- `readlink` will resolve any symbolic links along the way
- `dirname` takes just the directory name from script's full path - it's better readable and safer for corner cases than manually looking for slashes etc.

Now, you will get the correct result even in a complex case: if your script is in `/tmp` and you create a symbolic link to it in `/tmp/abc/`, and your current directory will be `/home` and you run `/tmp/abc/your-script`, it will correctly output `/tmp`, not `/home` nor `/tmp/abc`.

Comment: I think such an answer should start with `"Assuming that you need to use the location of the original script when you create a symlink of it under a different path..."`.